# Expo: Detect Face and Save To Api For Comparing Later

Tags: react-native, django-rest-framework, expo, face-detection

I'm trying to make my own system with Django-Rest-Framework which includes also register/login system for mobile application. I keep user informations in my Django server.

The deal is: I'm new at React-Native and there is really less any source or tutorial for face scanning an comparing. I need to learn how to scan face (with FaceDetector or something else) and save it to my server. I know how to send it to my server, I need to know "what should I save exactly". And that would be really good if I learn how to compare a saved face scan data with a new one (so I can authorize users).